# Conditional hooks when rendering static website

Tags: reactjs, server-rendering, react-static

I'm using react-static to generate a static website. Using `useLayoutEffect` from [the new hook API](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect), I get this warning during the static rendering phase (same API as server-side rendering) :

```
Warning: useLayoutEffect does nothing on the server, because its effect cannot be encoded into the server renderer's output format.
  This will lead to a mismatch between the initial, non-hydrated UI and th  e intended UI.
  To avoid this, useLayoutEffect should only be used in components that render exclusively on the client.
```

Of course this makes sense. **But what's the good option to get rid of this warning when one's sure there won't be any mismatch ?**

In my layout effect I'm only adding a bit of CSS to the `body` tag, so there won't be any mismatch during the hydration phase on the client (since `body` isn't React's business).

React strongly forbids using conditional hooks, but in that *very* specific case, wouldn't it make sense to do something like :

```
if(typeof window !== 'undefined')
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
      document.body.style.overflowY = loading ? 'hidden' : 'visible'
    },
    [loading]
  )
```

What's the proper way ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use a Context to pass the value "hidden/visible" to other components. In this case, the component that renders a wrapper of all the page.

```
useEffect(() => { 
  fnSetContextValue(isLoading ? 'hidden' : 'visible') 
}, [isLoading]);
```

You also can try with the [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame) function instead of a Context:

```
useEffect(() => { 
  window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      document.body.style.overflowY = loading ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
  });
}, [isLoading]);
```

Comment: Using `useEffect` instead of `useLayoutEffect` indeed doesn't trigger the warning, but then I lose the synchronous aspect of `useLayoutEffect`.

Comment: Oh, I wrote `useEffect` in my post, true. Corrected. I meant `useLayoutEffect`.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so here is the *not-so-dirty* solution I came up with. Instead of implementing the naive solution, ie. a conditional hook :

```
const Layout = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState()

  if(typeof window !== 'undefined')
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
      document.body.style.overflowY = loading ? 'hidden' : 'visible'
    }, [loading])

  return ( ... )
}

export default Layout
```

which feels dirty, anti-pattern, semantically wrong and useless in many cases (why checking `window` at each render ?), I just put the condition outside of the component :

```
const LayoutView = ({ loading, setLoading }) => ( ... )

const Layout = (typeof window === 'undefined') ? (
  () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState()
    return <LayoutView loading={loading} setLoading={setLoading}/>
  }
): (
  () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState()
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
      document.body.style.overflowY = loading ? 'hidden' : 'visible'
    }, [loading])
    return <LayoutView loading={loading} setLoading={setLoading}/>
  }
)

export default Layout
```

Take care though, this only works because my layout effect doesn't affect React's part of the DOM, which was the whole point of the warning.